# How can I start 10000 consumers with the command line?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I need to do a stress test.
So I need to start 10000 consumers.

What is the easiest way to do that?

Comment: Have you tried using a for loop?

Comment: @OneCricketeer yes but it doesn't run all the consumers at the same time.

Comment: `kafka-console-consumer... &` will send the process to the background, allowing others to run, like any other shell program

Comment: You could also use a simple Python consumer and multithreading module... Note that 10000 consumers in one consumer group is very different behavior than 10000 consumer groups with a single consumer each